# What constructions are considered not Korean and what's so bad about them?

Tags: grammar

Some say Korean people started to use grammatical constructions they weren't used to use as the language got influenced by many other languages, such as Japanese, Chinese, and English.

- What constructions are considered *foreign*, not *native*?
- And what are the good reasons to avoid them, apart from being not *native*?
- What makes constructions *Korean*?

Answer (score 3):

Leaving their grammatical correctness aside, such constructions relate to [번역체 문장](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B2%88%EC%97%AD%EC%B2%B4%20%EB%AC%B8%EC%9E%A5), 번역체, 번역 투, and other similar terms. Some are accepted and commonly used now; others, controversial; the others, wrong in a logical sense. Nevertheless, it is better to avoid using 번역체.

**Reasons**:

In the first place, Koreans *never* use *some* of 번역체 문장 in everyday life, which means that they will *not* consider those constructions correct. It is just that translators cannot help using them when there are no alternative ways. Look up words like 으로의 [here](https://kcorpus.korean.go.kr/). You will get *no* examples of *Korean* origin from the corpus.

Secondly, 번역체 문장 are mostly verbose or complicated, whereas well-written ones are simple and clear. We wish to have good communications with others; it requires learning how to use words and phrases properly. As for the English language, [a Korean](http://blog.naver.com/PostList.nhn?blogId=engstudio) wrote books for Koreans who wish to form better English sentences. It suggests that the grammatical correctness does *not* guarantee the goodness and appropriateness.

Besides, using 번역체 should be avoided to protect some grammatical rules. For example, 관하다 and 대하다 are 동사, but they have often been used as if they were 형용사. 동사 and 형용사 must have different conjugated forms. Although some claim that such verbs are also "불완전 동사" (defective verbs), I disagree with that classification because of the illogical forms such as 관한 and 대한. We may as well avoid using 관하다 and 대하다. More exceptions to the current rules would increase the difficulty of learning and using Korean.

A further reason is that the use of unexpected or unusual constructions could hinder the development of language translators and analyzers. In other words, 번역체 could heighten language barriers. Today, many people rely on machine translators and accept mistranslations as correct. We should prevent them from misunderstanding what others say or mistranslating what they say.

It is not a general reason, but there is also a historical one related to Japanese. During the colonial period, the Japanese government attemped to eradicate the Korean culture from Korea. For example, [the Korean language was removed from the school subjects in Korea in 1936](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Japanese_sentiment_in_Korea). They are still a lot of conflicts regarding the history between Korea and Japan. It is quite natural that Koreans dislike the constructions originated from the Japanese language.

*There may be more acceptable reasons, so I have marked this answer as "community wiki."*

**Bad constructions**:

(These are *just a few* examples regarding your questions.)

1. Those with *pronouns* unnecessarily placed

> 철수와 민수가 집에 왔다. 학교에서 혼이라도 났는지 **그들**은 시무룩한 표정을 지었다. (✘)
>
> 철수와 민수가 집에 왔다. 학교에서 혼이라도 났는지 **걔들**은 시무룩한 표정을 지었다. (✔)
>
> 철수와 민수가 집에 왔다. 학교에서 혼이라도 났는지 **둘**은 시무룩한 표정을 지었다. (✔, somewhat colloquial)
>
> **네**가 이 책을 읽으면 **네** 머리가 좋아질 거라고 **그들**이 말했어. (✘)
>
> 이 책을 읽으면 머리가 좋아진댔어. (✔)

2. Those with *그녀* (그녀 was made for translation)

   ```
   Use 그, 걔, or other phrases instead of 그녀.
   그 does not have gender: it means "she / he / the / it (its) / that (those)."
   걔 = 그 아이.
   ```

> 나는 **그녀**가 좋아. (✘)
>
> 나는 **그**가 좋아. (✔, somewhat literary and ambiguous)
>
> 나는 **걔**가 좋아. (✔, colloquial)
>
> 나는 **그 여자**가 좋아. (✔)

3. Those with *의* unnecessarily placed as a postpositional particle [(some other examples here)](http://www.ohmynews.com/NWS_Web/View/ss_pg.aspx?CNTN_CD=A0002249899)

   ```
   의 is often unnecessary even in grammatically correct sentences.
   ```

> 철수**의** 집에 민수**의** 친구가 놀러 왔다. (✘)
>
> 철수 집에 민수 친구가 놀러 왔다. (✔)
>
> 해외 시장**에의** 진출이 머지않았다. (✘)
>
> 해외 시장**에** 진출할 날이 머지않았다. (✔)
>
> 해외 시장**으로의** 진출이 머지않았다. (✘)
>
> 해외 시장**으로** 진출할 날이 머지않았다. (✔)
>
> 친구 사이에 흔히 있는 일 중**의** 하나는 놀다 싸우는 것이다. (✘)
>
> 친구끼리 놀다 싸우는 것은 흔히 있는 일이다. (✔)
>
> 국가**의** 이익보다 개인**의** 이익을 앞세우는 태도가 바람직한가? (✘)
>
> 국가 이익보다 개인 이익을 앞세우는 태도가 바람직한가? (✔)
>
> 국익보다 사익을 앞세우는 태도가 바람직한가? (✔)
>
> 저**의** 꿈**의** 집을 드디어 찾았어요! (✘, ambiguous)
>
> 제가 정말로 원하던 집을 드디어 찾았어요! (✔)
>
> 어제 한잔**의** 술을 마셨어요. (✘, logically wrong)
>
> 어제 (술을) 한잔했어요. (✔)

4. Those with *-들* used *for things* without any special reasons

> 사과**들**을 먹어라. (✘)
>
> 사과를 먹어라. (✔)
>
> 나는 쉴 때 책**들**을 읽는다. (✘)
>
> 나는 쉴 때 책을 읽는다. (✔)

5. Those with *제발* in place of "please" when the speaker is *not begging or showing anger*.

> **제발** 문을 닫아 주시겠어요? (✘)
>
> 문 좀 닫아 주시겠어요? (✔)

6. Those with the *double passive* (passive-passive combinations)

   ```
   Many Koreans make mistakes here; if you know this, you can have an advantage over them.
   You should also be aware that some causative-passive combinations are allowed.
   ```

> 찢**겨진** 종이가 여기에 있다. (✘)
>
> 찢**긴** 종이가 여기에 있다. (✔)
>
> 잊**혀진** 장소에는 사람이 가지 않는다. (✘)
>
> 잊**힌** 장소에는 사람이 가지 않는다. (✔)
>
> 그 사람 말이 틀렸다고 생각**되어진다**. (✘)
>
> 그 사람 말이 틀린 듯싶다. (✔)
>
> 그 사람 말이 사실로 믿**겨지지** 않는다. (✘)
>
> 그 사람 말이 사실로 믿**기지** 않는다. (✔)
>
> 책상 위에 놓**여진** 책을 봐. (✘)
>
> 책상 위에 놓**인** 책을 봐. (✔)
>
> 그 아이는 친구들에게 바보라고 불**려졌**다. (✘)
>
> 그 아이는 친구들에게 바보라고 불**렸**다. (✔)

7. Those with *가지다* when it is unnecessary

> 우리는 성대한 잔치를 **가졌다**. (✘)
>
> 우리는 성대한 잔치를 **벌였다**. (✔)

8. Those with the *present progressive* when it is unnecessary or inappropriate

> 뭐 하느냐고? 밥 먹**는 중이다**. (✘)
>
> 뭐 하느냐고? 밥 먹**는다**. (✔)
>
> 어디 가**고 있니**? (✘)
>
> 어디 가**니**? (✔)
>
> 이 고양이는 죽**어 있습니다**. (✘)
>
> 이 고양이는 죽**었습니다**. (✔)

9. Those with *인하다* and *의하다*

   ```
   Although these words are considered formal, we do not have to use them.
   ```

> 소문에 **의하면** 내일 민수 집에서 잔치를 한다고 한다. (✘)
>
> 내일 민수 집에서 잔치를 한다고 들었다. (✔)
>
> 그 소문은 목격자에 **의해** 부인되었다. (✘)
>
> 그 소문은 목격자가 부인하였다. (✔)
>
> 그 사고로 **인해** 사상자가 났다. (✘)
>
> 그 사고로 사상자가 났다. (✔)
>
> 그 사고 **때문에** 사상자가 났다. (✔)

10. Those with *비하다* when it is unnecessary

> 사진에 **비해** 실물이 낫다. (✘)
>
> 사진**보다** 실물이 낫다. (✔)
>
> 이 일이 그 일에 **비하면** 경비가 덜 든다. (✘)
>
> 이 일이 그 일**보다** 경비가 덜 든다. (✔)

11. Those with *시키다* instead of 하다

> 밧줄을 나무에 연결**시켰다**. (✘)
>
> 밧줄을 나무에 연결**했다**. (✔)
>
> 나한테 네 친구를 소개**시켜** 줘. (✘)
>
> 나한테 네 친구를 소개**해** 줘. (✔)

12. Those with *위하다* when it is unnecessary

    ```
    Although these words are used frequently, they are sometimes unnecessary.
    ```

> 나는 강해지기 **위해서** 운동을 시작했다. (✘)
>
> 나는 강해지**려고** 운동을 시작했다. (✔)

13. Those with *대하다* and *관하다* when they are unnecessary ([reference](http://www.hani.co.kr/arti/culture/book/115593.html))

    ```
    Although these words are used frequently, they are often unnecessary.
    ```

> 동사에 **관한** 공부를 하자. (✘)
>
> 동사를 공부하자. (✔)
>
> 내가 한 일에 **대하여** 비난하지 마. (✘)
>
> 내가 한 일을 비난하지 마. (✔)
>
> 우리 학교는 선행을 베푼 학생들에 **대하여** 상을 주었습니다. (✘)
>
> 우리 학교는 선행을 베푼 학생들에게 상을 주었습니다. (✔)

14. Those with *데/에/에게 + 있다*

> 내 꿈은 기업가가 되는 **데 있다**. (✘)
>
> 나는 기업가가 되고 싶다. (✔)
>
> 물은 사는 **데 있어** 중요하다. (✘)
>
> 물은 사는 **데** 중요하다. (✔)
>
> 음식량 조절은 당뇨병 환자**에게 있어** 중요하다. (✘)
>
> 음식량 조절은 당뇨병 환자**에게** 중요하다. (✔)
>
> 나무 심기는 환경 보호**에 있어** 중요하다. (✘)
>
> 나무 심기는 환경 보호**에** 중요하다. (✔)
>
> 진행 중**에 있는** 일을 중단하려는가? (✘)
>
> 일을 처리하다가 말려는가? (✔)
>
> 그는 이 분야**에 있어서** 둘째가라면 서러울 정도로 유명하다. (✘)
>
> 그는 이 분야**에서** 둘째가라면 서러울 정도로 유명하다. (✔)

15. Those with *입장(立場)*

    ```
    Use 상황, 처지, 주장, 관점, 방침, 의견, 견해, or others more clear in meaning.
    ```

> 나는 그럴 **입장**이 못 된다. (✘)
>
> 나는 그럴 **처지**가 못 된다. (✔)
>
> 그 사람은 우리가 이 일에 적극 대응하여야 한다는 **입장**을 밝혔다. (✘)
>
> 그 사람은 우리가 이 일에 적극 대응하여야 한다는 **견해**를 밝혔다. (✔)
>
> 우리는 정부에 비판적인 **입장**을 보인다. (✘)
>
> 우리는 정부를 비판한다. (✔)

16. Those with "을/를 필요로 하다" instead of "이/가 필요하다" ([related to this question](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/546/%ed%95%84%ec%9a%94%ed%95%98%eb%8b%a4-%ed%95%84%ec%9a%94-%ec%9e%88%eb%8b%a4-%ed%95%84%ec%9a%94%eb%a1%9c-%ed%95%98%eb%8b%a4-whats-the-difference-in-meaning-and-usage))

> 우리는 도움**을 필요로 한다**. (✘)
>
> 우리는 도움**이 필요하다**. (✔)

17. Those with *superlatives (제일/가장 ...) for plural things/people (...들)*

> 저곳에 가면 **가장 멋진** 집**들**이 보인다. (✘)
>
> 저곳에 가면 무척 멋진 집이 여럿 보인다. (✔)
>
> 세상에서 **제일 아름다운** 배우**들**이 한곳에 모였다. (✘)
>
> 정말로 매우 아름다운 배우들이 한곳에 모였다. (✔)

18. Those with *stationary or abstract things as subjects when verbs relate to actions*

    ```
    They are for special use (e.g. writing patent documents) not for everyday use.
    ```

> 이 연구 결과**는** 개가 관심에 민감하다는 점을 **말하여 준다**. (✘)
>
> 이 연구 결과**에서 (우리는)** 개가 관심에 민감하다는 점을 **알 수 있다**. (✔)

19. Those with *그럼에도 불구하고*

> 지금 눈이 많이 내립니다. **그럼에도 불구하고** 차를 몰려고 하십니까? (✘)
>
> 지금 눈이 많이 내립니다. **그런데도** 차를 몰려고 하십니까? (✔)
>
> 어제 눈이 많이 왔습니다. **그럼에도 불구하고** 눈이 많이 쌓이지는 않았습니다. (✘)
>
> 어제 눈이 많이 왔습니다. **그러나** 눈이 많이 쌓이지는 않았습니다. (✔)
>
> 어제 눈이 많이 왔습니다. **그렇지만** 눈이 많이 쌓이지는 않았습니다. (✔)

20. Those with *에 틀림없다*

> 저기에 있는 사람은 여자임**에 틀림없다**. (✘)
>
> 저기에 있는 사람은 여자**가 틀림없다**. (✔)
>
> 그 정책은 미봉책임**에 틀림없다**. (✘)
>
> 그 정책은 미봉책**이다**. (✔)

21. Those with *경우* when it is unnecessary

> 소문은 대부분의 **경우** 헛소문이다. (✘)
>
> 소문은 대부분 헛소문이다. (✔)

22. Those with *적(的)* unnecessarily placed as a postpositional particle [(some other examples here)](http://www.ohmynews.com/NWS_Web/View/ss_pg.aspx?CNTN_CD=A0002249899)

> 국가**적** 이익보다 개인**적** 이익을 앞세우는 태도가 바람직한가? (✘)
>
> 국가 이익보다 개인 이익을 앞세우는 태도가 바람직한가? (✔)
>
> 국익보다 사익을 앞세우는 태도가 바람직한가? (✔)
>
> 이 지역은 절대**적** 다수가 어민들이다. (✘)
>
> 이 지역은 절대다수가 어민들이다. (✔)

23. Those with *의 그것* meaning *that/those of*

> 서울의 거리는 부산**의 그것**보다 붐비는가? (✘)
>
> 서울은 부산보다 거리가 붐비는가? (✔)
>
> 서울 거리는 부산 거리보다 붐비는가? (✔)
>
> 어른의 몸무게는 아기**의 그것**보다 많이 나간다. (✘)
>
> 어른은 아기보다 몸무게가 많이 나간다. (✔)

---

Please note that there are more examples on the Web and in publications. If you find any errors, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It is a complicated problem: people have different opinions (which may or may not match the language they actually speak), and there are a fair amount of nationalism (some of which may or may not be justified by Korea's modern history).  So, consider this as my personal attempt at a "reasonable" answer, but expect some native speakers to disagree in many parts.

I think there are issues in both directions:

- During the past 100 years or so, Korea went through rapid modernization and imported tons of new words.  Frequently, people imported words and expressions with little concern on how they sound in Korean or if they conflict with the original meaning.  It still happens now: it's easy to find awkward expressions where you can almost feel the original English phrase.

  You can find some extreme cases in the so-called [보그체](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B3%B4%EA%B7%B8%EC%B2%B4), named after the fashion magazine *Vogue*.  (Warning: trying to understand the page is not advised for beginners of Korean.)
- On the other hand, perhaps as a reaction, the quest for a platonic, uncorrupted "pure" Korean has enjoyed wide support.  Due to Korea's centralized history (Seoul was a capital since 1394) and rapid urbanization in the late 20th century, Korea's political/cultural power concentrated at Seoul, and hence the search for "ideal" Korean usually meant codifying an idealized speech of Seoulites: the "definition" for the standard Korean (표준어) is literally "modern Seoul speech widely used by cultured people" (교양 있는 사람들이 두루 쓰는 현대 서울말).  In early 90s, I remember school textbooks literally teaching that using a (non-Seoul) dialect demonstrates one's lack of education.

  A variant view is that the Seoul dialect is *not* an ideal Korean, because it is already too corrupted by foreign influence.  For example, see [this quote](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%9D%B4%EC%98%A4%EB%8D%95) from 이오덕, a famous writer and "pure Korean" activist:

  > 밖에서 들어온 잡스런 말을 세 가지로 나눌 수 있으니, 첫째는 중국글자말이요, 둘째는 일본말이요, 셋째는 서양말이다. 이 세 가지 바깥말이 들어온 역사도 중국글자말-일본말-서양말의 차례가 되어 있는데, 중국글자말은 가장 오랫동안 우리 말에 스며든 역사를 가지고 있지만, 일본말은 중국글자말과 서양말을 함께 끌어 들였고 지금도 끊임없이 끌어들이고 있다는 점에서 그 깊은 뿌리와 뒤엉킴을 잘 살펴야 한다. 정말 이제 우리가 정신을 바짝 차리지 않으면 넋이 빠진 겨레가 될 지경에 이르렀다는 것을 똑똑히 알아야겠다.

  While disagreeing on what constitutes an ideal Korean, these views however agree on the *existence* of an ideal Korean: somehow they always find the Korean language in a great peril of decay, and fear that it will commence the end of Korea's culture, "ethnic spirit (민족혼)", and independence.

---

Now, we can see why this is so complicated: depending on who you ask, expressions can be either too foreign or too "pure" (i.e., feels like it was made up just for the sake of being a pure Korean expression).

- By the way, if anyone is interested in these issues, **I highly recommend 고종석's 감염된 언어** (English translation: [*Infected Korean Language*](http://www.cambriapress.com/cambriapress.cfm?template=4&bid=586) by Koh Jongsok).  (Despite the title, it's actually about how these "infections" made Korean a richer language.)

The following is some cases I can think of, but it's by no means exhaustive, and of course you'll find disagreements.

- Hanja words that has been traditionally used, but changed meaning due to Japanese influence.

  For example, 방송(放送) used to mean "to release a prisoner", but now it means "broadcast".  생산(生産) meant "to give a birth", but now it means "production".  You won't find the original meaning unless in a historical drama.
- Hanja words imported from Japanese.

  There are tons of them: 산소(酸素 oxygen), 전화(電話 telephone), 화학(化學 chemistry), and so on.  Most of them are well establisehd in Korean and will not likely to go away.

  On the other hand, sometimes people do "import" a new Japanese word carelessly, and end up with an expression that sounds slightly "off".
- Hanja words imported from *native* Japanese words.

  This happens because some native Japanese words are still written in Kanji: 입구(入口 entrance), 취소(取消 cancel), 할인(割引 discount).  (Koh's book has more examples.)  Some linguistic purists actually oppose words like 할인.
- Idioms/expressions borrowed from Japanese.

  They have varying degrees of acceptance.  Frequently, what's common in written texts are rare in speech.  Examples include -에의 and friends (e.g., 무도회로의 초대), 보다 in place of 더 (보다 큰 내일), or 그/그녀(he/she - though it's debatable which language we borrowed it from).  Of course, you can find people who want to abolish *all* of them.
- Native Japanese words.

  Perhaps because they *obviously* sound Japanese, most of them fell out of fashion: 와리바시(->나무젓가락), 사라(->접시), 즈봉(->바지), 이빠이(->가득), 다마네기(->양파), etc.  Though some survives: 오뎅, 우동, 스시, 짬뽕, 쓰나미, etc.

  And I personally use 바께쓰(<-bucket, the correct term will be 물통 or 양동이) and 빤쓰(팬티) without shame - my grandma used them, and so will I.  (I probably won't use them in a "serious" writing, though.)

  One amusing example is "뒷담화" (talking behind one's back) - it is from "뒷다마", where 다마 is the Japanese word for a billiard ball, so it originally meant "hitting the back of a billiard ball", but then it became retrofitted to 담화 (a very serious word for "conversation"), and now everybody's using this cleaned-up spelling.
- English words that either do not have a good Korean counterpart, or have largely replaced them.

  Examples (and possible alternatives): 컴퓨터(전자계산기), 인터넷, 버스, 엘리베이터(승강기), 컵(잔), 샐러드, etc.

  Sometimes people try to come up with native (or Hanja) alternatives, like 소프트웨어->무른모.  They usually fail, although some terms like 누리집(<-website) gained wider acceptance.
- English words/phrases that somehow keep appearing even though there are perfectly good Korean alternatives.

  Government initiatives are particularly guilty of them, such as "사이언스 북 스타트 운동".  These days you have subway stations named 캠퍼스타운 and 센트럴파크.  And of course, all these brand names and movie titles.
- Poorly translated English expressions or grammar.

  Examples include: overuse of 그/그녀, inappropriate use of inanimate subjects, and a lot of passive construction (which is very limited in Korean).

  One interesting example I remember is the word 환상적.  When I was young, the word only meant "related to fantasy", as in 꿈을 찾아 떠나는 환상적인 이야기.  Due to the English word *fantastic*, now people keep using it to mean "great", as in:

  > 영국을 국빈방문 중인 도널드 트럼프 미국 대통령이 "런던 방문은 정말 잘 되고 있다"며 "여왕과 왕족 전체가 환상적이었다"고 만족감을 나타냈습니다.
- Pure Korean words/expressions revived from obsolescence.

  If done right, they can sound great.  Other times, they may sound weird or pretentious.  (Of course it's highly subjective - some word may sound pretentious, because so few people know it, but then it may become popular, and then because everybody know the word, it won't be pretentious any more.)

  Some words did get a new life this way: I think 톺아보다 (to examine closely) is probably in the middle of being revived.

  ...and believe it or not, sometimes people make up [fake pure Korean words](https://namu.wiki/w/%EA%B0%80%EC%A7%9C%20%EC%88%9C%EC%9A%B0%EB%A6%AC%EB%A7%90)!