# 떠나서 vs 불구하고 - Differences?

Tags: translation, spoken-korean, written

These two expressions or endings, whatever it is properly called,

seem to convey similar things.

- Are these interchangeable?
- When would you use one over another?

**My understanding:**

`떠나서` - Understanding but `going away` from a certain topic/reason
and focusing on others.

`불구하고` - This means, despite that? So, while addressing something, a topic/reason is acknowledged, but not valid in this moment or topic.

Comment: You use “-을/를 떠나서” when not taking a particular factor into account, while “-도 불구하고” has a meaning of overcoming it. Similar, but not identical senses.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are *not* interchangeable.

Regarding your second question, it would be helpful to regard -을/를 떠나서 as [*apart from*](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/apart_from/synonyms). Please consider the following examples:

> - 사회나 국가는 개인**을 떠나서**는 존재하지 못한다. (except for)
> - 독서가 좋은지 싫은지**를 떠나서** 어떤 책을 읽어야 할지도 모르겠다는 사람이 많다. (in addition to)
> - 우리는 결과**를 떠나서** 열심히 노력했다는 데에 의의를 두었다. (without regard to)

On the other hand, -에도/ㄴ데도/은데도/는데도 불구하고 can be used to mean *despite*, *in spite of*, *although*, or *even though* (but *not* as in *despite myself*). Nonetheless, 불구하고 is always unnecessary ([link](https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/5263/2162)).

> - 아버지는 경기 침체**에도 불구하고** 사업을 벌였다. (My father ... despite the recession)
>
>   = 아버지는 경기 침체에도 사업을 벌였다.
> - 세상에는 독서를 싫어함**에도 불구하고** 책을 사는 사람도 있다. (In the world, ... despite their dislike of reading)
>
>   = 세상에는 독서를 싫어함에도 책을 사는 사람도 있다.
> - 평균 수명이 계속 느는**데도 불구하고**  노인 복지 수준은 그대로이다. (Despite the ever-increasing average life expectancy, ...)
>
>   = 평균 수명은 계속 느는데도 노인 복지 수준은 그대로이다.
> - 이 산은 경치가 좋**은데도 불구하고** 등산객으로 붐비지 않는다. (Despite the good scenery of this mountain, ...)
>
>   = 이 산은 경치가 좋은데도 등산객으로 붐비지 않는다.

Comment: “-을/를 떠나서” has another meaning than you described: regardless of; leaving (a particular factor) aside; besides. “승패*​​​​​를 떠나서* 두 팀 모두 열심히 싸워 주었다. (Both teams did great, _regardless of_ their results.)”

Comment: @КонстантинВан I have added an example according to your comment. Both -을/를 떠나서 and *apart from* seem highly ambiguous.